# link anchors in HTML email

Tags: html, email

I am trying to make a newsletter email with an idnex that has links to different anchors in the mail, but so far, it doesn't seem to work in any client. This is the code:

```
<ul style="list-style: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; ">
  <li><a href="#anchor1">Sehen wir uns auf der ISH?</a></li>
  <li><a href="#anchor1">Sehen wir uns auf der ISH?</a></li>
  <li><a href="#anchor1">Sehen wir uns auf der ISH?</a></li>
  <li><a href="#anchor1">Sehen wir uns auf der ISH?</a></li>
  <li><a href="#anchor1">Sehen wir uns auf der ISH?</a></li>
</ul>

...

<a name="anchor1" id="anchor1">foo</a>
```

What?s even weirder, in GMAIL my ID tag disappears and my name tag gets some sort of weird prefix, like "124335132_anchor1". What could I do?

Comment: Hi there. I know this is a pretty old post and you might've forgotten but could I ask what approaches did you follow for your solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Email clients aren't web browsers or designed to be. They leave off vast swathes of things you are likely to consider "pretty basic".

Make all links absolute and plan for them to open in a web browser.

Comment: I know, but the customers wants an index at the beginning of the mail that intra links to the sections of the same :(

Comment: I want to quit my job and have a truck full of money pull up and deliver me a case of £10 notes every day.  :) Sadly, neither I, nor your customer is going to get what they want.

Comment: But IT IS possible to make anchor links inside an email, isn't it?

Comment: @Dbugger — Oh yes, you can make them — but will the email client support them? You've not had much success.

Comment: I meant anchor links THAT WORK. I mean they should work in AT LEAST one client, but they dont work in any :(

Comment: Email clients aren't designed to load URLs into the main window (only for dependancies like emails). Support for URLs with fragment ids on the end is a natural outcome of supporting URLs in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

you know how usually you have the string

```
<div id="boom">...
```

and you want to anchor link to that from somewhere else, you would enter

```
<a href="#boom"></a>
```

so now you would use a name tag in addition to your destination.

```
<a name="boom"></a><div id="boom">...
```

Viola! anchor link in html email.

Comment: Do note this mostly works. However, I just tested this technique on iPhone's Mail client and it does not work so our Marketing team is compromising a bit based on this technical constraint.

Comment: Thanks. I've searched all the internet and this is the only working solution for Outlook Client (desktop or web).

Answer (score 0):

To work with outlook 2010, it has to be like that:

```
<a href="#section1">Jump to section!</a>
<p>A bunch of content</p>
<a name="section1">An anchor!</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

not sure i'm getting what you mean.. but, it looks like you wanted to send MIMEBody as an email content, so the email looks like an html format.. if it the case, here is some piece from my java code:

```
@Override
    public void coba() {
        try {

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
            message.setSubject("Whatever");
            message.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("SomeEmail@email.com", "SomeName Name"));

            //
            // This HTML mail have to 2 part, the BODY and the embedded image
            //
            MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");

            // first part  (the html)
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            String htmlText = "<div style=\"width:800px; background-color:#525252\"><h1>Header</h1></div><br /><div style=\"width:200px; background-color:#ff0000; float: left\"><h3>Navigation Panel</h3><ul><li>link <a href=\"http://google.com\">here</a></li><li>link <a href=\"http://google.com\">here</a></li></ul></div><div style=\"width:600px; background-color:#727272; float: left\"><h3>Content</h3><p>blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla</p><br /><img src=\"cid:image\" /></div>";
            messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");

            // add it
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // second part (the image)
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource fds = new FileDataSource("C:/img/lion.JPG");
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID","<image>");

            // add it
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // put everything together
            message.setContent(multipart);

            Transport.send(message);

            //System.out.println("Successfully Send Email(" + subject + ") to " + emailAddress);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

i send an email with html format, here is screen shot the message content on gmail

[here is the screen shot](http://i52.tinypic.com/2055c13.jpg)

hopefully it have any use for you..