# Does Outlook 365 support Anchor Links in Emails in the Emailclient?

Tags: email, outlook, anchor, html-email, email-client

I am trying to make an anchor Link work in Outlook
Version: 2103 (Build 13901.20400 ...)

My code is quite simple:

```
 <a href="#e">Link</a>
 ...
 <table id="e" name="e" >
```

Also Note that it works in the browser version of Outlook.

So either Outlook doesn't support anchor links like these, or I need to know how it should be done.

I know that this issue was present in the past in earlier version of outlook, but It would be nice to know for sure, whether there just a trick to it that I couldn't find or if the search will not yield anything.

Hopefully that saves people time.

Comment: Outlooks desktop versions support anchor but from experience it displays different part of the document when clicked. So there is 50/50 chance it will work.

Comment: Hmm.., but do you know on what can depend? e.g. do specific tags not work but others do?

Comment: The only solution i've found to this anchor issue is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457999/link-anchors-in-html-email

Answer (score 0):

The anchor element is fully supported by Outlook and its rendering engine. But how it works really depend on Word which is used for rendering message bodies in Outlook.

Comment: Pre 2007 works fine as its using IE I assume?